# Troubleshooting "AudioQueueObject::IONodeConnection::_AcquireHardwareCodec: failed ('hwiu')" when playing sound file

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, codec

> [Error]: 21:46:56.148 [AudioQueueServer] AudioQueueObject::IONodeConnection::_AcquireHardwareCodec: failed ('hwiu')

That's an error I am getting when playing a sound file. Is this a codec issue or a problem with the sound file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/musicaudio/reference/audioconverterservicesreference/Reference/reference.html), that error, 'hwiu', means "Hardware in use".  The hardware codec is unavailable.  If you are creating your own AudioQueue, you can set the hardware codec policy to `kAudioQueueHardwareCodecPolicy_PreferSoftware`, which will try the software codec first and fallback on the hardware codec, e.g.:

```
AudioQueueSetProperty(yourQueue, 
                      kAudioQueueProperty_HardwareCodecPolicy,
                      &kAudioQueueHardwareCodecPolicy_PreferSoftware,
                      sizeof(kAudioQueueHardwareCodecPolicy_PreferSoftware));
```